# Query all Beans of Application Context

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring application.xml (I have many XML in Blueprint Context)

```
<bean name="bean1">
  <property name="list">
     <list>
       <bean class="com.jrey.xx.A"></bean>
       <bean class="com.jrey.xx.C"></bean>
     </list>
  </property>
<bean name="bean2">
  <property name="list">
    <list>
      <bean class="com.jrey.xx.A"></bean>
      <bean class="com.jrey.xx.B"></bean>
   </list>
 </property>
```

with the getBeanDefinitionNames method I can get the beans bean1,bean2 but I cannot get the list items, I want scan this beans too.

```
for (String beanName : applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
  //I have a control
}
```

What is the way to retrieve all beans of application context, that include the beans that not have names and beans items of a list.

Comment: What is your Spring version?

Comment: Have you tried `applicationContext.getBeansOfType(Object.class)` ? It returns a Map of all the beans that are an Object type. It initializes them too, so using it simply like that will maybe generate errors

Comment: getBeansOfType does not show me all beans.. Now I did test it. Thanks

Comment: @André I am using Spring 3.2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. If you want to be able to reference those beans, declare them with a name at the top level of the XML configuration and reference them within the `<list>`.

```
<bean name="A1" class="com.jrey.xx.A" />
<bean name="bean2">
  <property name="list">
    <list>
      <ref bean="A1" />
   </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to do some more general.. Do you have any idea to add to my beans some proxy interceptor.

Comment: What do you mean by _proxy interceptor_?

Comment: Each bean can be a Service, with a annotation @CustomAcl And I must check if the thread can execute that method.. I want to do some generic... for all jars of my project. (another person can add more jar)

Comment: Think that my explanation is out of this question

Comment: Yeah, it seems like you should ask a new question with all the relevant details.

Comment: Thanks, By the moment I will use your answer. But I am going thinking how to resolve if is possible another way.